# Annual dividend yield using option prices

Tags: option-pricing

If I have only strike, call and put prices for European options, how do I work towards computing the continuous dividend yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a call/put pair with the same strike $K.$  Then a position long the call and short the put has the payoff of a forward struck at $K:$
$$C(K) - P(K) = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}[ S(T) - K ],$$
Where $C(K)$ and $P(K)$ are the call and put price, $r$ is the interest rate, and $T$ is the time to expiry.  Then by linearity of expectation and the martingale property 
$$ \mathbb{E}[ S(T) ] = e^{(r-q)T}S(0),$$
we can solve for dividend rate $q.$

Comment: Thanks! But isn't r The risk free rate there?

Answer (score 0):

Consider two different strikes $K_1$ and $K_2$. Then, for $i=1$ and $2$,
\begin{align*}
C(K_i)-P(K_i) &= e^{-r T}E(S_T-K)\\
&=e^{-qT}S_0 - e^{-rT}K_i.
\end{align*}
Now, the two unknown parameters $r$ and $q$ can be solved from the two equations.